# Affineness of the algebra of formal power series?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, formal-power-series

Let $\mathbb{k}$ be a field and $A$ be a commutative $\mathbb{k}$-algebra. It is clear that when $A$ is an affine $\mathbb{k}$-algebra (that is, $A$ is finitely generated as a $\mathbb{k}$-algebra), the polynomial algebra $A[x]$ is affine both as $\mathbb{k}[x]$-algebra and $\mathbb{k}$-algebra. **So it is natural to ask if $A[[x]]$ is affine as a $\mathbb{k}[[x]]$-algebra when $A$ is affine?** (I know that $A[[x]]$ is not affine as a $\mathbb{k}$-algebra in general).

Intuition says no, but I have no idea how to prove or disprove it. After some thinking, I found that suppose $A$ can be generated by $\{a_{1},...,a_{m}\}$, then $A[[x]]$ may not be generated by $\{a_{1},...,a_{m}\}$ as a $\mathbb{k}[[x]]$-algebra in general. For example, consider the polynomial algebra $A=\mathbb{k}[y]$, which can be generated by $y$ . It is clear that $\mathbb{k}[[x]][y]\subsetneq \mathbb{k}[y][[x]]=A[[x]]$. And now I feel stuck.

Can you give me a hint or something more? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $k$ is any ring and $V$ is $k$-module that is not finitely generated.  Then I claim that $V[[x]]$ is not countably generated as a $k[[x]]$-module.  In particular, if $V$ is additionally a $k$-algebra, this implies $V[[x]]$ is also not countably generated as a $k[[x]]$-algebra.

To prove this, take any countable sequence of elements $(f_n)$ in $V[[x]]$; we will show it does not generate $V[[x]]$ as a $k[[x]]$-module.  Since $V$ is not finitely generated, for each $n$ we can pick an element $a_n\in V$ which is not in the submodule generated by any of the coefficients of $f_0,\dots,f_n$ for powers of $x$ less than or equal to $n$.  Now consider the element $a=\sum a_nx^n\in V[[x]]$.  If $a$ were a $k[[x]]$-linear combination of $f_0,\dots,f_n$, then for each $m$, $a_m$ would be a $k$-linear combination of the coefficients of $f_0,\dots,f_n$ for powers of $x$ less than or equal to $m$.  But by construction, this is false for $m=n$.  Thus $a$ cannot be a $k[[x]]$-linear combination of $f_0,\dots,f_n$ for any $n$, so it is not in the submodule generated by the entire sequence $(f_n)$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Eric. As you said, $V[[x]]$ is not countably generated as a $k[[x]]$-module when $V$ is a $k$-module that is not finitely generated, and hence my question has been answered very well.   But I wonder why a commutative algebra , say $A$, over a commutative ring $R$ that is countably generated as an $R$-algebra must be countably generated as an $R$-module? I can only see that any commutative affine $R$-algebra is countably generated as an $R$-module.

Comment: If $A$ is generated by an algebra by elements $a_i$, then it is generated as a module by the set of all products of the $a_i$.

Comment: You are right. What I wanted to ask before is why the set of all products of the $a_{i}$ is countable.  But now I understand~ Thanks!