# Freeness of the algebra of formal power series?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, formal-power-series

Let $\mathbb{k}$ be a field and $A$ be a commutative $\mathbb{k}$-algebra. Then the algebra of formal power series $A[[x]]$ can be viewed as a $\mathbb{k}[[x]]$-module in a natural way. **My question is whether $A[[x]]$ is a free $\mathbb{k}[[x]]$-module**.

Note that $\mathbb{k}[[x]]$ is a P.I.D. and $A[[x]]$ is a torsion-free $\mathbb{k}[[x]]$-module, so $A[[x]]$ must be flat as a $\mathbb{k}[[x]]$-module. Since $A[[x]]$ may not be finitely generated as a $\mathbb{k}[[x]]$-module, the structure theorem for finitely generated modules over a P.I.D. is invalid here.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Note that no use is made of the algebra structure of $A$ here so it is really a vector space over $k$. The answer is yes if $A$ is finite-dimensional and you can take a set of free generators to be any basis of $A$; that construction fails if $A$ is infinite-dimensional so I bet the answer is no in that case but I don't see a proof off the top of my head.

Answer (score 2):

If $A$ is finite-dimensional as a $k$-vector space then trivially $A[[x]]$ is a free $k[[x]]$-module (any basis for $A$ over $k$ is also a basis for $A[[x]]$ over $k[[x]]$).  On the other hand, if $A$ is infinite-dimensional, then $A[[x]]$ is never a free $k[[x]]$-module.  Since a submodule of a free $k[[x]]$-module is free, it suffices to prove this in the case that $A$ is countable-dimensional.  In that case, note that as shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4773653/86856), $A[[x]]$ is not countably generated as a $k[[x]]$-module, so if it were free, its rank would have to be uncountable.  However, $A[[x]]/xA[[x]]\cong A$ is countably generated as a $k[[x]]/(x)\cong k$-module, so $A[[x]]$ cannot be free of uncountable rank.

Comment: Oh, very nice! I had the idea of $A[[x]]$ not being countably generated but I didn't see that last step that finishes it.

Comment: Thank you for your nice answer! Now I get it. :D